# Strange behavior of collection view for string

Tags: scala

I was answering another question and tried to write this code:

```
val view = "0000000000".view
println(List(0,12,30,4).foldLeft(view)((s, i) => s.updated(i, '1')).mkString)
```

But this actually doesn't compile, and I had to convert it to seq and add an ugly type ascription for it to work.
I've noticed that `"0000".view` returns `SeqView[Char, String]` which is probably correct, but then when I do `"000".view.updated(0, '1')` it returns `Seq[Char] = SeqViewP(...)`.

I'd expect it to return the same `SeqView[Char, String]`. Is this a bug, or am I missing something? What is the best way to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you need to convert the `String` to a view? Could you not just leave it as a `String`? This will be converted to a "string-like" `SeqLike[Char]` on an as-needed basis by an implicit conversion to `StringOps`, which ensures that the returned type for operations like `.updated(...)` will still be `String` Eg.:

```
println(List(0,12,7,4).foldLeft("000000000000000")((s, i) => s.updated(i, '1')).mkString)

// prints: 100010010000100
```

Note: I upped the length of the `String`, and changed one of the values in your list just to avoid issues with index values larger than the `String`'s length, but how you prefer to deal with that problem is a different issue.

Comment: I'd do the same, but I'm trying to make it the most efficient, as that what was asked in the question I was trying to answer. If `updated` will return new string, this operation will spam short-living strings in memory and is memory and performance unwise. Is this correct?

Comment: In terms of efficiency, you might want to consider building up a mutable buffer of chars and convert it to a `String` at the end, rather than make a `String` and update it. Something like: `List(0, 12, 7, 4).sorted.foldLeft(ListBuffer.empty[Char])((buf, i) => buf.padTo(i, '0') :+ '1').mkString`

Comment: Thanks, that's actually nice idea, I didn't think of that. But I still want to know why `view` behaves differently in this case. I think being able to use `view` on strings is an important part of collection api

Comment: Let's say I want to proove that you can write efficient fp code in Scala, which means immutable

Comment: the `.updated` method on `SeqView` has a return type of `Seq`, not `SeqView`. You can call `.view` on this, but that returns a `SeqView[Char,Seq[Char]]`, rather than a `SeqView[Char,String]` (note that `String` is _not_ a `Seq[Char]`, but can be implicitly treated as one via implicit conversion to `StringOps`). Making your view-based code work led me to: `println(List(0,12,7,4).foldLeft[SeqView[Char, Seq[Char]]](view.view)((s, i) => s.updated(i, '1').view).mkString)`.

Comment: I would note that - while Scala can be very efficient when used in functional style - there can be occasions when nothing will beat the efficiency of using a local mutable value (and indeed the implementation of quite a few of Scala's immutable class' methods do just that). The question becomes whether / where it is worth that extra iota of performance; or whether it amounts to premature optimisation, and good, functional, composable code will be the better choice for expressiveness, scalability and maintainability (while still getting at least good performance).

Comment: the `.updated` method on `SeqView` has it's return type coming from `CanBuildFrom` pattern. This means that if it results in `Seq` in the end, the wrong `CanBuildFrom` gets hooked.  Notice that `val a = Seq(1, 2, 3, 4).view; a.updated(2, 2)` returns a proper `SeqView`. So it is clearly where  it goes wrong - because our `Seq` is `Seq[Char]` not `Seq[Int]` and for some reason `CanBuildFrom` is choosen badly. Then I am lost - I am not sure how can I debug `CanBuildFrom`. But I think you've convinced me to try to report this as a bug and see it next there